# Need help about number orders

Tags: text, paste, libreoffice

I have a number set as shown below;

140080066

90110439

110100255

110090248

10120539

150130043

150130045

40120258

10130133

150130142

50120473

50120521

40130224

Some numbers are 8 order some are 9. I want to add "0" (Zero) to left of the number which has 8 orders. After the process the numbers should be like;

010120539

110100255

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: I format the column of the set as text and with this command ="0"&C2 I can add 0 to left. But sure It adds 0 to all numbers. I need to add the 0 only the 8 orders one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the formula

```
=IF(LEN(A1)=8,0&A1,A1)
```

in any column and set format cell to text or set format cell in column as number and put `000000000` in Format code field

Answer (score 0):

I think more context is required.
Since you tagged "libreoffice" you wanna do it with a macro?
If so, you can use the len-operator to test if the value is 8 or 9 digits long.

More info:
http://www.debugpoint.com/2014/11/string-processing-in-libreoffice-calc-macro-with-examples/